# Apache reverse proxy to dynamic ports

Tags: apache, port, reverse-proxy

Can I configure Apache to reverse proxy paths such as `/foo/1234/bar/` to `http://localhost:1234/bar/`? In other words, I'd like to capture part of the path as the port number to reverse proxy.

I'll also have to reverse proxy websockets using the same principle: `/foo/1234/bar/ws` to `ws://localhost:1234/bar/ws`

I have a partial solution:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} websocket [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Connection} upgrade [NC]
    RewriteRule    ^/foo/(\d*)/(.*)/ws$   ws://localhost:$1/$2/ws [P,L]
    RewriteRule    ^/foo/(\d*)/(.*)$      http://localhost:$1/$2 [P]
```

This seems to work well for http, but the websocket is not forwarded. I got a 404: `GET /foo/7681/xxx/ws HTTP/1.0" 404` in my logs.

Answer (score 1):

It works actually. My problem comes from another reverse proxy that stands before my server. I leave the question here since it could help others (I did not find this answer anywhere else).